# Как правильно настроить RestTemplate, для работы в Spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, десериализация, resttemplate

Хочу из приложения Spring Boot создать запрос на стороннее API, получить ответ в виде готового объекта Currency и далее работать с ним. То что сейчас имею - restTemplate возвращает объект, но все поля у него null, если этот запрос вбиваю в строку браузера - вижу адекватный JSON ответ.

Класс CurrencyAPI, который содержит метод для работы с restTemplate:

```java
import by.andrew.bot.telegrambotmonitor.classesRespThirdPartyAPI.Currency;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Component
public class CurrencyAPI {
    private final String URL_CURRENCY_RATE = "https://www.nbrb.by/api/exrates/rates/USD?parammode=2";
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public CurrencyAPI(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }

    public Currency getCurrencyRate(){
        Currency currency = restTemplate.getForObject(URL_CURRENCY_RATE, Currency.class);
        return currency;
    }
}
```

И сам обьект, который должен быть создан из полученного JSON:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Currency {
    private int cur_ID;
    private String cur_Abbreviation;
    private String cur_Name;
    private Double cur_OfficialRate;

    public int getCur_ID() {
        return cur_ID;
    }

    public void setCur_ID(int cur_ID) {
        this.cur_ID = cur_ID;
    }

    public String getCur_Abbreviation() {
        return cur_Abbreviation;
    }

    public void setCur_Abbreviation(String cur_Abbreviation) {
        this.cur_Abbreviation = cur_Abbreviation;
    }

    public String getCur_Name() {
        return cur_Name;
    }

    public void setCur_Name(String cur_Name) {
        this.cur_Name = cur_Name;
    }

    public Double getCur_OfficialRate() {
        return cur_OfficialRate;
    }

    public void setCur_OfficialRate(Double cur_OfficialRate) {
        this.cur_OfficialRate = cur_OfficialRate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Десериализация JSON из URL

Библиотека [`FasterXML/jackson`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) позволяет десериализовать объект из различных типов источников. Например, чтобы прочитать JSON из URL можно использовать метод [`readValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.net.URL,%20java.lang.Class)) класса `ObjectMapper`. Нужно подготовить POJO класс, в который десериализовать JSON, или, если структура заранее не известна, то можно десериализовать в `Map` или `Object`:

```java
URL url = new URL("https://www.nbrb.by/api/exrates/rates/USD?parammode=2");
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map map = objectMapper.readValue(url, Map.class);
System.out.println(map);
```

Вывод:

```
{Cur_ID=145, Date=2020-11-25T00:00:00, Cur_Abbreviation=USD,
 Cur_Scale=1, Cur_Name=Доллар США, Cur_OfficialRate=2.5548}
```

---

См. [Десериализация строки JSON](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1210268/417380)